# CosmosDb. How to retrieve the _ts property from a Upsert operation

Tags: c#, azure-cosmosdb

Using the .NET 3 SDK for CosmosDB my upsert operation on an existing document does not return any of the extra properties stored in the document E.G. the _ts property. I would like to use this property in my app. Do I have to include a _ts property in my model or is there a way to retrieve _ts from the document?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Do I have to include a _ts property in my model?

If you're working with a typed model, then the answer is yes. You will need to create a property corresponding to `_ts` property of the response otherwise the deserializer will not be able to deserialize this.

Another option would be to work with `dynamic` type and do the conversion into the model yourself. For example, you could do something like:

```
var model = new Model()
{
    Id = "some id",//should serialize to "id",
    //other properties of the model
}

var item = (await container.UpsertItemAsync<dynamic>(model)).Resource;
Console.WriteLine(item.ToString());
```

Above would print something like the following:

```
{
  "id": "783cf82c-f24c-4031-971d-bd5f604724d5",
  "_rid": "xxxx",
  "_self": "dbs/xxxx/colls/xxxx/docs/xxxx/",
  "_etag": "\"xxxx\"",
  "_attachments": "attachments/",
  "_ts": 1621597233,
  //other model properties
}
```

You can now extract the "_ts" property from the JSON.

Comment: Would this approach work if the model was already stored in the db?

Comment: Yes. `_ts` is a system property so it is automatically set by Cosmos DB engine and is present in every document.